# How to match the first value of the grains in saltstack?

Tags: linux, salt-stack

I would like to  get the first value of eth0.
I would like to set a variable.

```
hardware_interface:
  eth0:
      10.0.2.16
      192.168.34.11
  lo:
      127.0.0.1
```

Below is my variable declaration in state file and it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
{% set interface = grains['hwaddr_interfaces'][0] %}
{% set ip = grains['ipv4'][1] %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a dictionary (hwaddr_interfaces) so you do not have direct access to the value with the index.

```
{% set interface = salt['grains.get']("hwaddr_interfaces", []) %}

# {{ interface.keys() }}
# {{ interface.keys() | first }}
# {{ interface.keys()[0] }}
```

This will output the following thing when doing a salt-call -l debug:

```
...
# [u'lo', u'virbr0', u'virbr0-nic', u'eth0']
# lo
# lo
...
```

When you are using the .keys() you get an array.
If you want the first element, using the jinja `| first` should be enough. otherwise `interface.keys()[idx]`

Once you have the name of the interface you can retrieve the associated array with:

```
{% set res = salt['grains.get']("hwaddr_interfaces:"+interface.keys()[0], []) %}
```

For the ipv4 part, it should be working as it is an array:

```
{% set ip = salt['grains.get']('ipv4')  %}

# {{ ip }}
# {{ ip | first }}
# {{ ip[1] }}
```

output:

```
# [u'127.0.0.1', u'192.168.1.34', u'192.168.122.1']
# 127.0.0.1
# 192.168.1.34
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood it now